# Let's make our site an excellent repository of frequently asked significant questions about Hinduism!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, suggestions

Internet has become a repository of information today. Though there are many question-answers about Hinduism on websites and forums but the quality & reliability of StackExchange *surpasses* that of other sites.

Many people are looking for the information on various topics of Hinduism on the web but we know that they don't find correct/reliable information on internet always. So, it would be great help and beneficence/obligation if we provide right and correct information on those topics here.

So, I'm proposing the following idea:

If / Whenever you find a very good, interesting and important question that people look for frequently and deserves to be a good Q/A post on this site, post it. If you've knowledge about that topic, then you're encouraged to share in Q/A (say [self-answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)) form.

- This will make our site good knowledge base for such frequent and significant questions.
- This will  increase questions per day and % answered stats on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism).
- This may also increase the chance of users joining the site as StackExchange posts are [nicely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14056/260388) [indexed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187431/260388) with search engines like Google.

Thanks.

<sup>Note for beginners: Visit [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), how to [ask a good question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [write a good answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Always insist on citing authoritative and reliable sources and references in the answer.</sup>

Comment: What about: [Should I search on Internet before asking question?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/224/2995)

Comment: @sv. That also says -- "If your question is interesting, unanswered by search, you think may be helpful to others if I post it here, than ask, nothings wrong in asking a question which is searchable online, so that users get authentic information from this site."